# How can I explain succinctly the grading system used at my university?

Tags: formality, numbers

I'm writing a certificate and I've to write that the student's project achieved the grade 8.0. However, I need to explain succinctly the grading system used.

I try the following:

> The student has undergone the project during the period February 2017 to May 2017 and presented it in October 2017, achieving the grade 8.0 (grade 0.0 means unsatisfactory and 10.0 means excellent)

Could you please correct any mistake I may have made or a more suitable(formal) way to express the situation?

p.s.: The satisfactory grade is 5.0, below the student fails and above passes the course.

Comment: You might indicate at what point (5.0? 6.0?) a grade crosses the line between failing and passing.

Comment: The point is 5.0. I edited the post and added this information. Thanks

Comment: I would replace "has undergone" with "completed"—but I would also say that this question amounts to a request for proofreading and is therefore off-topic at this site.

Comment: Do not ask for help writing (or proofreading). “How should I write this?” and “is this correct?” questions are out of scope and your question may be removed. See: “[What topics can I ask about here? - Help Center](/help/on-topic)”. If there is an unstated specific concern, such as “What does (word) mean in context?” or “How does (grammar or punctuation rule) apply in context?” ask that question instead. Also check out “[Where can I ask for free proofreading? – Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7571)”, and the *[Writers Stack Exchange](https://writers.stackexchange.com/)*.

Answer (score 1):

One customary way of indicating how good a score is is by using "out of":

> The student has undergone the project during the period February 2017 to May 2017 and presented it in October 2017, achieving the grade 8.0 (out of a potential 10).

There's no need to explicitly say that you rank zero as "unsatisfactory" on this scale, or 10 as "excellent". Getting full marks (10 out of 10) is at the top end; zero out of ten at the bottom end.

If you do need to rate the score, then add that:

> The student has undergone the project during the period February 2017 to May 2017 and presented it in October 2017, achieving the grade 8.0 (out of a potential 10), which passed and was considered *good*.

From [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/out_of):

> **out of**
>
> 3. From among (a number)
>    *‘To pass the examinations a score of 6 out of ten had to be achieved.’*

Answer (score 0):

The student has participated in the project from February, 2017 to May, 2017, inclusive and successfully completed all requirements in October, 2017 achieving a grade of 8.0 (our grade scale ranges from 0.0 which is unsatisfactory to 10.0 meaning excellent). 
I must say it is a little confusing when you say he underwent a project from February to March and presented it (the project?) in October.

Comment: Exactly. The project was carried out in another country and he had to present it (the project) in my/our country, because of that and among other factors, he had to put the presentation off to a later time. And I had to take it into account in this certificate.Thanks for your help